# What value of $c$ makes this Riemannian metric complete?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I was given the following question in my differential geometry class. The instructor does not use a textbook, and gives only theorems and proofs with no examples, so I don't know how to do computations. Here is the problem:

Let $g = (1-x^2-y^2-z^2)^{2c}(dx \otimes dx + dy \otimes dy + dz \otimes dz)$, where $c$ is some real number, be a Riemannian metric on the open unit ball $B = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x^2+y^2+z^2 <1 \}$. What values of $c$ makes this metric geodesically complete?

Can someone explain how to do this question? Thank you.

Comment: Incidentally, your metric is defined on the open _unit ball_, not the unit sphere $S^{2}$.

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang You are right, I will edit that.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Consider the Riemannian metric on $(-1, 1)$ with arc length element
$$
ds = (1 - x^{2})^{c}\, dx.
$$
For what $c$ is the distance from $0$ to an end of the interval infinite?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are saying I should compute $\int_0^1 ds = \int_0^{\pi/2} (1-x^2)^c dx$, which by trig substitution gives $c  \leq -1$ then the integral does not converge. Is that right? I'm quite unfamiliar with Riemannian geometry, how is this related to my original question? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your conclusion is correct, though you can get by without trig substitution: It's enough to see $(1 - x^{2})^{c} \sim [2(1 - x)]^{c}$ near $x = 1$. :) The connection is, your metric $g$ is fully rotation-invariant, the arc length element in the radial directions is $(1 - x^{2})^{c}\, dx$, and the distance (in the metric) from the origin to the boundary of the ball is $$\lim_{t\to1^{-}}\int_{0}^{t} (1 - x^{2})^{c}\, dx,$$the [arc length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold#Riemannian_manifolds_as_metric_spaces_2) of a radial segment.